# How can I convert any file to binary mode in c#?

Tags: c#

How can I convert any file like .exe or .doc .....etc to binary mode in c#

Comment: What is the format you call "binary mode"?

Comment: You're not asking the question the smart way. Tell us what you're *actually* trying to accomplish, and we'll be able to provide much better help. See here for more question-asking tips: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: If you can improve the question so that it is understandable, do so and flag for moderator attention so we can reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is read a binary file into a binary array object in c# then you can use a [binary stream reader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) as described in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) MSDN article.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BinaryReader to read your file. Please find code sample below:

```
public byte[] FileToByteArray(string _FileName) 
{
   byte[] buffer = null;
   try
   {
      // Open file for reading 
      System.IO.FileStream _FileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(_FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open,System.IO.FileAccess.Read); 
      // attach filestream to binary reader 
      System.IO.BinaryReader _BinaryReader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(_FileStream); 
      // get total byte length of the file 
      long _TotalBytes = new System.IO.FileInfo(_FileName).Length; 
      // read entire file into buffer 
      _Buffer = _BinaryReader.ReadBytes((Int32)_TotalBytes); 
      // close file reader 
      _FileStream.Close(); 
      _FileStream.Dispose(); 
     _BinaryReader.Close(); 
 catch (Exception _Exception) 
 {
   // Error 
   Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in process: {0}", _Exception.ToString()); 
 }
 return _Buffer;
}
```